# Amazon API submitting requests too quickly

Tags: amazon-product-api

I am creating a games comparison website and would like to get Amazon prices included within it. The problem I am facing is using their API to get the prices for the 25,000 products I already have.

I am currently using the ItemLookup from Amazons API and have it working to retrieve the price, however after about 10 results I get an error saying 'You are submitting requests too quickly. Please retry your requests at a slower rate'.

What is the best way to slow down the request rate?

Thanks,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> If your application is trying to submit requests that exceed the maximum request limit for your account, you may receive error messages from Product Advertising API. The request limit for each account is calculated based on revenue performance. Each account used to access the Product Advertising API is allowed an initial usage limit of 1 request per second. Each account will receive an additional 1 request per second (up to a maximum of 10) for every $4,600 of shipped item revenue driven in a trailing 30-day period (about $0.11 per minute).

From [Amazon API Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/TroubleshootingApplications.html)

If you're just planning on running this once, then simply sleep for a second in between requests.

If this is something you're planning on running more frequently it'd probably be worth optimising it more by making sure that the length of time it takes the query to return is taken off that sleep (so, if my API query takes 200ms to come back, we only sleep for 800ms)

Answer (score 0):

Since it only says that after 10 results you should check how many results you can get. If it always appears after 10 fast request you could use

```
 wait(500)
```

or some more ms. If its only after 10 times, you could build a loop and do this every 9th request.

Answer (score 0):

when your request A lot of repetition.
then you can create a cache every day clear context.
or Contact the aws purchase authorization

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same problem even if I put 1 or more seconds delay.

I believe when you begin to make too much requests with only one second delay, Amazon doesn't like that and thinks you're a spammer.

You'll have to generate another key pair (and use it when making further requests) and put a delay of 1.1 second to be able to make fast requests again.

This worked for me.