# RequestThrottled: You are submitting requests too quickly. Please retry your requests at a slower rate

Tags: amazon-product-api

I submit this request:

```
from amazonproduct import API
api = API(locale='us')
result = api.item_search('Furniture', Keywords = 'sofa', Availability='Available')
```

and get back the error

```
RequestThrottled: AWS Access Key ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX. You are submitting requests too quickly. Please retry your requests at a slower rate.
```

I know this question was already asked 2 years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911443/amazon-api-submitting-requests-too-quickly). But I only submit one request.

Also, a similar question was asked [here](https://github.com/t3chnoboy/amazon-product-api/issues/104) more than a year ago. The answer posted 25 days ago was:

> Solved adding the domain in request:
> domain: 'webservices.amazon.es'

However, 'domain' doesn't appear to be a parameter of amazon's [ItemSearch API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html).

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon deactivated our account because we didn't produce enough revenue.

Comment: I didn’t. It wasn’t a programming problem after all.  They deactivated our account

Comment: Indeed, according to the documentation: «Effective 23-Jan-2019, the request limit for each account is calculated based on revenue performance attributed to calls to the Product Advertising API (PA API) during the last 30 days.» and «Note that your account will lose access to Product Advertising API if it has not generated referring sales using PA API in the last 30 days.» See the Efficiency Guidelines section on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/TroubleshootingApplications.html. Note that it appears that generating sales via SiteStripe should get you access.

Answer (score 3):

From Jan 2019 amazon has changed it's api usage policy. API feature is mapped with sale you made in last month.

If you are facing this error means you have not made any sale in your last month. For reference kindly visit https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/TroubleshootingApplications.html

Comment: The reason "You are submitting requests too quickly" is misleading as it is actually caused by lack of referring sales. Amazon should correct the wording of the error message & be less restrictive. Instead of completely blocking access due to lack of referring sales, they could at least allow access & may be limit number of requests

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you submit too many requests while testing. Additionally to a maximum limit per second, there is also a limit per day and month:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/TroubleshootingApplications.html#efficiency-guidelines

If you use the Python wrapper, the domain is already added to your request.